# Shiny how to incorporate dec icon using htmltools syntax question

Tags: html, css, shiny

I need to show an icon (◼) using `dec` but my html skills are very limited.

What I am trying and need adjusted:

```
htmltools::tags$span("I will display"  , style="&#9724;"),
htmltools::tags$span("I will display"  , style="#9724;"),
htmltools::tags$style("I will display" , style="&#9724;"),
htmltools::tags$style("I will display" , style="#9724;"),
```

How do I show the icon above using shiny's tagging system?

https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/tryit.asp?deci=9724&ent=FilledSmallSquare

EDIT: updated. I need the icon to be part of the `DT` caption.

```
datatable(
  head(iris),
  caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
    style = 'caption-side: bottom; text-align: center;',
    'Table 2: ', 
htmltools::tags$span("I will display"  , style="&#9724;"),
htmltools::tags$span("I will display"  , style="#9724;"),
htmltools::tags$style("I will display" , style="&#9724;"),
htmltools::tags$style("I will display" , style="#9724;"),
  )
)
```

Comment: thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`htmltools` escapes HTML content by default, so the ampersand in the HTML entity will end up escaped like this:

```
> htmltools::span("&#9724;")
<span>&amp;#9724;</span>
```

You can use raw HTML with `htmltools::HTML()` like:

```
DT::datatable(
  head(iris),
  caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
    style = 'caption-side: bottom; text-align: center;',
    'Table 2: ', 
    htmltools::HTML("<span>I will display &#9724;</span>")
  )
)
```

or include the symbol in the string without HTML escaping:

```
DT::datatable(
  head(iris),
  caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
    style = 'caption-side: bottom; text-align: center;',
    'Table 2: ', 
    htmltools::tags$span("I will display ◼ or \u25fc")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add icon in shiny you can use `ìcon`.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  htmltools::tags$span("I will display", icon("square"))
)
server <- function(input, output) {
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, icons are not working, otherwise I would have used them. I need to use them in the DT caption.